# PET Kitchen Backsplash

Tags: kitchens, backsplash

I need a new kitchen backsplash. Would like something cheap, easy to cut and install, preferably white or transparent and possibly a single large piece.

I believe that PET might be a good material for it: I could find some nice transparent sheets of PET 3x2 meters big for like 60$. I couldn't find much about it on the internet though.

Would PET be a good material for a kitchen backsplash? Any hints?

Comment: 4-1/4" wall tile is extremely inexpensive. It's also fairly easy to install. Any reason you're not going with something more attractive than plastic?

Comment: I think you'll have a lot of trouble installing a transparent piece in a way that is functional and not horribly ugly. You can't glue it because the glue would be visible, so you'd only be able to attach it at the edges. If you can fit it *exactly* then some silicon sealant might do the trick, but it'll be really difficult to put in and if you mess up a cut, the whole piece is garbage.

Comment: I think you'd be much further ahead using standard wall tile, or some of the "peel and stick" tiles (which will probably be more expensive and not look as nice, but can be done very quickly with little skill and only a knife/scissors).

Comment: At the orange big box, we sold thermoplastic panels that you glue up as a backsplash and looked like pressed metal panels.  That's a relatively inexpensive route if you're trying to avoid the standard "subway" tiles for some reason.